# Wkwebview overlying and hiding the toolbar

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am using wkwebview to show a webpage but it is overlaying the toolbar. If I remove 
view = webView Then the toolbar can be seen but not the webpage. Been going around in circles with this and tried several possible solutions in other threads but nothing is working. Here is my code...

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate{

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   let url = URL(string:"website address")!
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

          let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
          webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true



}



}
```